# Can't read .properties file from library to spring maven project

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have one maven spring project (as a library) and I am adding it as a dependency into spring maven project(web service).
I have some properties files in both projects. In library there is one validationmessages.properties file.
I am using hibernate validator annotations on my model.
For example,
@NotBlank(message = "{NotBlank-entityId}")
Private String entityId;

The class model which is in library,using as a request body in webservice.here library hibernate validation messages are not working in webservice.
Here's the code:
Model:
Task.java (In library)

```
public class Task {

@NotBlank(message = "{NotNull-EntityID}")
  private String entityId;

public String getEntityId() {
    return entityId;
  }

  public void setEntityId(final String entityId) {
    this.entityId = entityId;
  }
}
```

Taskvalidationmessages.properties (In library)

```
NotNull-EntityID = Entity ID can not be null.
```

TaskManagementConfiguration.java (In library)

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:queries.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:Taskvalidationmessages.properties") })
@Import(DataSourceConfiguration.class)
public class TaskManagementConfiguration {

}
```

TaskResource.java (Controller in webservice project)

```
@RequestMapping(value = WebserviceConstant.CREATE_TASK, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = WebserviceConstant.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public ResponseEntity<CreateTaskResponse> createTask(
      @Valid @RequestBody final Task request,
      @RequestHeader(value = "access-token") final String accessToken) {

    return new ResponseEntity<CreateTaskResponse>(
        taskService.createTask(request, receivedToken), HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

App.java (In Web service project)

```
@Configuration

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:user-queries.properties") })

@Import({ TaskManagementConfiguration.class })
public class App {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

}
```

Whenever I hit the resource url with empty value of entityId.
It gives error like:

```
{
  "fieldErrors": [
    {
      "field": "entityId",
      "code": 200,
      "message": "{NotNull-EntityID}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please paste your exact code and what do you mean 'not working' what is the message value?